# how to execute multiple stored procedures and pass parameter using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

Initially I had one stored procedure and everything was running good but the requirement has changed now and I would like to call multiple stored procedures and pass a parameter. I am using `Execute SQL Task` and here is my query where it calls only one stored procedure:

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_TEST]
 @Code =?
[PEDS].[up_InitialClear]
```

The above works well but I need to be able to call other stored procedure and pass the same parameter here. How can I call `sp_TEST1`, `sp_TEST2` and pass the same parameter? Thanks

Comment: Can you use 2 separate Execute SQL Tasks for that?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply execute them separately like below .

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_TEST] @Code

EXEC [PEDS].[up_InitialClear] @Code
```